# Built-in function to convert numeric vector into a probability distribution?

Tags: r

Say I have a vector:

```r
x <- c(0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0, -0.1)
```

I want to transform it such that negative values are replaced by 0 and the sum totals 1. I can easily define a function that does this:

```r
to_dist <- function(x) {
  non_negative <- pmax(x, 0)
  
  non_negative / sum(non_negative)
}

to_dist(x)
# [1] 0.375 0.375 0.250 0.000 0.000
```

But I was wondering if a built-in function already exists.

Comment: `proportions(pmax(x,0))`

Comment: @onyambu That should be an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following **@onyambu**'s comment:

```r
proportions(pmax(x, 0))
```